# Export Thematic Raster Files algorithm in eCognition not resulting in Raster output

Tags: ecognition

I am trying to export a classification from eCognition in raster format and have tried both the Export Thematic Raster Files and Export Classification View algorithms and get a generic File as an output.
I specified the .img as the output format and tried all three options for the Export Type and all resulted in the same generic "File".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have had the best luck exporting results as a shapefile and converting to raster using the GIS software (ArcMap in my case).

[image]